# Accessing the same service more than twice in the nick of time

Tags: c#

I have an application that will access interface service A which is to run from windows startup. This service is used by program B and my application functions on B's presence after getting a pointer to A. 
The scenario is translated as follows,

```
public interface A{}
///my program
public class MyProgram
{
    public MyProgram()
    {
      ProgramB.DoA();
    }
    public A GetA(){}
}

public class ProgramB
{
   void DoA(){}
}
```

The translated source is not true, but that seems to be what I am looking for. In order to eliminate the overhead of allocating and realocating dynamic accesses to the same service used by other processes, would you please provide an actual solution to the problem ?(I am all out of any idea now)

Comment: So `ProgramB` is another process and `A` is yet another process? How are they communicating with each other? Also, I really don't understand what exactly are you asking. What overhead are you talking about? Are you sure that overhead is actually a problem for you?

Comment: for stuff like that, I'd consider singleton or better yet, queue

Comment: @gnat would you care to elaborate in an answer instead of a comment how a singleton or a queue would help the OP? Like svick, I'm don't quite understand yet what the question is.

Comment: @PersonalNexus if I had time I'd write an answer instead of comment. But I don't have it now sorry. 1) design queue or singleton to serialize access to service 2) cache as needed to avoid duplicate accesses

Comment: I think @gnat is alluding to a [Service Locator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern) with his singleton suggestion. One option I haven't seen mentioned is use of a service architecture, like a web service or WCF server/client.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fathom your intent (and the question title is opaque as well), but if I understand what you are asking WCF supports duplex communication.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx

If you are running the service (A) and the client (B) on the same box, you can use a NamedPipe binding which is pretty straightforward. There's a tutorial implementation here that might be helpful:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wcf-tutorial-events-and-callbacks

If I've misunderstood your question, please disregard.